# How can I use multiple paths in Files block of .htaccess?

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, directory

Here is my code into `.htaccees` file:

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|sql)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

Now I want to add a directory path next to `index.php`. So the second block looks like this:

```
.
.
<Files index.php, /myweb/files>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

But it doesn't work. Noted that `<Files index.php | /myweb/files>` doesn't work either. What's the right syntax?

---

**Edited:** Now I have two `.htaccess` files. One of them is into root:

```
Options -Indexes

<Files ~ "\.(php|sql)$">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Files>

<Files index.php>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
</Files>
```

And the other one is into `/myweb/files` folder:

```
Allow from all
```

But sadly I cannot access `.php` files that are into `/myweb/files` .. How can I access them?

Comment: *... the directives given within this section will be applied to any object with a basename (last component of filename) matching the specified filename* not a directory. For a directory you should mind `<Directory>` directive. Also note that two consecutive, comma-separated file names are not allowed outside quotes.

Comment: @revo How can I say *"all files of `/myweb/files` directory"* ?

Comment: Just type what you say `<Directory "/myweb/files">`

Comment: I see @revo, And how about two directories? `<Directory "/myweb/files, /myweb/classes">`

Comment: Use Regular Expressions `<Directory ~ "^/myweb/(files|classes)">`. Check [`<Directory>` docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#directory) for more information.

Comment: @revo Ok thank you

Comment: @revo As my last question, do you know what's `~` in `<Files ~ "\.(php|sql)$">` ?

Comment: It enables you to use Regular Expressions within its parameter.

Comment: Ah I see, thank you @revo

Comment: @revo When I use [`<Directory>`](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/dbd40bafce7debcadde4aee96e37754f) in `.htaccess` file, it throws `Server error! Error 500`. Do you know what's wrong?

Comment: `<Directory>` directive isn't allowed in .htaccess files.

Comment: @anubhava Yes I got it. But now, I created a `.htaccess` file into that directory and added `Allow from all` in it. But still I cannot access php files that are in it. Do you know why?

Comment: @anubhava Updated.

Comment: @anubhava Or at least how can I exclude specific directory for `<Files ~ "\.(php|sql)$">` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use this code in `/myweb/files/.htaccess` to allows access to allow `*.php` files in `files/` directory:

```
<Files ~ "\.(php|sql)$">
   Allow from all
</Files>
```

Comment: How will be handled when we have multiple .htaccess files and don't want to use apache anymore? For example I want to use nginx from know, how should I hanlde multiple .htaccess files?

Comment: Just one question: Is using such codes into `.htaccess` file good *(performance perspective)* ? Or I have to put all directories out of document root instead of controlling accessibility via `.htaccess`?

Comment: @anubhava Ah ... But I'm talking about project structure. Let's ask why we use `.htaccess` file? To avoid accessing a file by others. Right? What if we place all project's files out of document root and use absolute paths? Then no one can access them. In that case we can even remove `.htaccess` file. Because no need to it anymore. So which manner is better? Either using `.htaccess` *(http server config)* or using *Single Point Of Entry* structure?

Comment: Using `mod_rewrite` rule in `.htaccess`  or http server config is actually better than using MVC because doing it in MVC would be essentially using some PHP code for doing routing, blocking etc. `mod_rewrite` is invoked much before loading `php` and is much cleaner and efficient.

Comment: @anubhava I see. You're right .. But you know, I'm worried about the performance. Each request should be checked for this pattern `<Files ~ "\.(php|sql)$">` and probably the IP should be checked too *(depends on that block's statements)*. Isn't that check per each request too much?

Comment: But you need that check per request anyway. if not .htaccess, you will be doing same check using some PHP code.

Comment: @anubhava Hmm, yes, what you said sounds right. Just one question, is converting .htaccess to nginx hard? For example do you know what's the equivalent of `Options -Indexes` in nginx?

Comment: Sorry I don't know nginx that well to be able to answer this one.

Comment: @anubhava Ok my last question: Does `Options -Indexes` work as recursively? Or I have to make a .htaccess file in each directory and add  `Options -Indexes` in it to avoid directory list ?

Comment: It is global (effective in all child subdirectories underneath) so you don't need to have this in every .htaccess

Comment: Why there isn't `Order Deny,Allow` line in your answer? When should it be used?

Comment: That is needed only when we use both allow and deny directives in same section.

Comment: @anubhava Ah I see, thank you. Just what's the difference  between `Order Deny,Allow` and `Order Allow,Deny`? When should I use which one?

Comment: Not much difference actually. They just tell which directive `(Allow or Deny)` will appear first below.